# getting clang warining as pass by value and use std::move?? why am I getting this warning

Tags: constants, stdmove

This build is in C++,

```
class DataHandler 
 DataHandler::DataHandler(conststd::shared_ptr<teh::cdp::m_presistentcacheInterface(persistentCacheInterface) {}
```

getting clang warning as pass by value and use std::move

```
DataHandler::DataHandler(conststd::shared_ptr<teh::cdp::m_presistentcacheInterface(persistentCacheInterface) {}
```

`persistentCacheInterface` value should pass to `m_presistentcacheInterface`. we cant use std::move or we can not change it to non const